# Document Version Storage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server-2012

In **SharePoint 2013** my understanding is that each `version` of a **document** is stored as a `delta` of the **original document**.

> i.e. each version takes less size on disk (in the content database)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

In sharePoint 2013 , yes it's correct by dint of `Shredded Storage` that is enabled by default

Based on what's the changes that you have to do  , it should only save the changes from the previous document , not the full document.

**For example,**

- Suppose a user is working with a 10 MB Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation and makes a change — either adding a new slide, removing a slide, modifying attributes, etc.—and saves the file back to the document library where it was initially accessed.  In this scenario, only the portion of the file related to the change is written to the database.
- if you upload a new document with the same name and extension that totally has different content and bigger than the old one in this case, when the version size should be the size of the changes that it approximately the file size.

  - E.g : if you have a file size is 1 MB, upload file with 2 MB and totally different content . in this case, the current version size should be 2 MB not diff 1 MB, because the changes are 2 MB.

for more details check [Overview of Shredded Storage in SharePoint 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39719)

Comment: In SharePoint if a new document is added with the same name and extension then it overwrites the existing, thus creating a new version.  Could you clarify your answer as this subject is important for capacity planning?

Comment: in this example , I talk also about changes if you upload a file with the same name but totally different content so the changes that will be saved is the total content file that it approximately the file size , please tell me if you don't get my point , Note : I put in my mind you enable Shredded Storage ,   I also will update my answer with example and I advise you to read the above-attached URL

Comment: @motionpotion For example : if you have a file size is 1 MB, upload file with 2 MB and totally different content .  in this case,  the current version size  should be 2 MB not diff 1 MB, because the changes are 2 MB

Comment: Is Shredded Storage not enabled by default in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: No, it's enabled by default

Comment: please tell me if you need more clarification